# Add cookie and undefined value for the first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

```
<script>

function favoritos(id)
{
    var actcookies=$.cookie("favshop);

    if (actcookies=="")
    {
        var insertcook=""+id+",";
    }
    else
    {
        var insertcook=""+actcookies+""+id+",";
    }
    ///

    $.cookie("favshop",""+insertcook+"",{expires:1000000});
}

</script>
```

**Call Add value the same Cookie**

```
> <div onclick="favoritos('<?php echo trim($post->ID);?>');"> Add
> Favourite Item </div>
```

The problem it´s when I add cookie values the first value show the number of id post and also undefined, for example **undefined634**,456,342,345 , but this don´t happend when add others cookies values the same cookie

I don´t know why add this undefined because the other values add without problem and don´t show undefined

Answer (score 0):

var actualcookies=$.cookie("favshop); missis " on the left

try on your php and
also,, maybe removing the ' ' from the onclick:

actcook is not "" it never is
It is undefined and u need to check for that instead of an empty string

```
    if(actcookies  == undefined )
```

Comment: I fix when writte here you can see the code other time , but results don´t change

Comment: can u make a fiddle/snippit out of it?

Comment: @Anton your jsfiddle is resulting in syntax errors so it isn't working.